# How to solve with LinkButton Click event and also find that ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, updatepanel, linkbutton

I have a problem with linkButtons that has click event is not fired i want to use same event for link buttons and when i click any linkButton the bind data to Repeater that is city wise
Below is my code :

```
<ul id="filter-tours" class="filter-out">
                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBenglore" runat="server" CommandArgument="benglore" OnClick="lnkCity_Click" >Benglore</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkVadodara" runat="server" CommandArgument="vadodara" OnClick="lnkCity_Click">Vadodara</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        <li class="header" >
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAhmedabad" runat="server" CommandArgument="ahmedabad" OnClick="lnkCity_Click">
                                <div class="header-outer">
                                    <div class="section-header">
                                        <div class="circle-outer">
                                            <div class="inner-1">
                                                <div class="inner-2"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span>Ahmedabad</span>
                                        <div class="head-bottom-bar"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSurat" runat="server" CommandArgument="surat" OnClick="lnkCity_Click">Surat</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPune" runat="server" CommandArgument="pune" OnClick="lnkCity_Click">Pune</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkMumbai" runat="server" CommandArgument="mumbai" OnClick="lnkCity_Click">Mumbai</asp:LinkButton></li>

                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Repeater id="rptHotel" runat="server" >

                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <div class="tours-wrapper">
                            </HeaderTemplate>

                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="tour <%# Eval("CityName") %>" style="margin-right:5px !important;">
                                    <div class="tour-visual"> 
                                        <a href="SearchHotel.aspx?HotelID=<%# Eval("HotelID") %>" >
                                            <img src="Admin/Hotel/Main/<%#Eval("Logo")%>" alt="" />
                                            <div class="hover"></div> 
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="head">
                                        <a href="SearchHotel.aspx?HotelID=<%# Eval("HotelID") %>" >
                                            <%#Eval("HotelName")%>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tag-line">
                                        <%# Limit(Eval("Address"), 55)%>, <%#Eval("CityName")%>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rate">
                                        <div class="rating" >
                                            <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" 
                                                StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                                                FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" CurrentRating='<%# Eval("Rating") %>' >
                                            </asp:Rating>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="records">
                                        <span class="icon-map-marker"><a href="#">show maps</a></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tour-bottom-line"></div>
                                    <a href="SearchHotel.aspx?HotelId=<%# Eval("HotelID") %>" class="booknow">Book Now</a>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </div>
                            </FooterTemplate>

                        </asp:Repeater>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkBenglore" EventName="Click" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkVadodara" EventName="Click" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkAhmedabad" EventName="Click" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkSurat" EventName="Click" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkPune" EventName="Click" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkMumbai" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and code behind code is:

```
protected void lnkCity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myConnectionString = "my connection string";

        LinkButton lnkCity = sender as LinkButton;

        if (lnkCity.CommandArgument.Equals("benglore"))
        {
            rptHotel.DataSource = null;
            rptHotel.DataBind();

            int cityID = 2;
            rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
            rptHotel.DataBind();
        }
        else if (lnkCity.CommandArgument.Equals("vadodara"))
        {
            rptHotel.DataSource = null;
            rptHotel.DataBind();

            int cityID = 3;
            rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
            rptHotel.DataBind();
        }
        else if (lnkCity.CommandArgument.Equals("ahmedabad"))
        {
            rptHotel.DataSource = null;
            rptHotel.DataBind();

            int cityID = 1;
            rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
            rptHotel.DataBind();
        }
        else if (lnkCity.CommandArgument.Equals("surat"))
        {
            rptHotel.DataSource = null;
            rptHotel.DataBind();

            int cityID = 4;
            rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
            rptHotel.DataBind();
        }
        else if (lnkCity.CommandArgument.Equals("pune"))
        {
            rptHotel.DataSource = null;
            rptHotel.DataBind();

            int cityID = 5;
            rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
            rptHotel.DataBind();
        }
        else if (lnkCity.CommandArgument.Equals("mumbai"))
        {
            rptHotel.DataSource = null;
            rptHotel.DataBind();

            int cityID = 6;
            rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
            rptHotel.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Comment: no issues with your code, its fine only.
check once any java script errors suppressing the page post back...

Comment: hi sunil i got my problem i solved it but in this there is a minor problem that is i used updatepanel but when i clicked on link button first time then it work perfect but second time don't work

Comment: hi sunil can you solve my problem, my problem is that when i remove updatepanel then it work perfect and it refresh page but i don't want to refresh page i want to update/refresh only partial part of page that is repeater so please help me.

Comment: i didn't found any issues with the code you posted above , i copied your code and tried the same. its always working fine.
as i told you earlier it's due to some other problem.
Do one thing, remove everything from your page apart from the link button and repeater and try now, so that you know the actual problem.

on more suggestion is, why don't you keep link buttons also in the same update panel so that you can remove the triggers node completely?

Comment: you means i use all link button inside update panel and remove triggers?

Comment: yes, before that have you tried by keeping only link buttons and repeater in page?

Comment: thanks sunil i solved my problem it is in js file now it work perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ItemCommand Event of Repeater, your code will be like this

```
protected void rpHotel_ItemCommand (object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName.Equals("benglore"))
    {
        rptHotel.DataSource = null;
        rptHotel.DataBind();

        int cityID = 2;
        rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
        rptHotel.DataBind();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName.Equals("vadodara"))
    {
        rptHotel.DataSource = null;
        rptHotel.DataBind();

        int cityID = 3;
        rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
        rptHotel.DataBind();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName.Equals("ahmedabad"))
    {
        rptHotel.DataSource = null;
        rptHotel.DataBind();

        int cityID = 1;
        rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
        rptHotel.DataBind();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName.Equals("surat"))
    {
        rptHotel.DataSource = null;
        rptHotel.DataBind();

        int cityID = 4;
        rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
        rptHotel.DataBind();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName.Equals("pune"))
    {
        rptHotel.DataSource = null;
        rptHotel.DataBind();

        int cityID = 5;
        rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
        rptHotel.DataBind();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName.Equals("mumbai"))
    {
        rptHotel.DataSource = null;
        rptHotel.DataBind();

        int cityID = 6;
        rptHotel.DataSource = dalMST_Hotel.SelectTop4(cityID, myConnectionString);
        rptHotel.DataBind();
    }   
    }   
}
```